# Do i have to declare Aspnet hosting permissions attribute to custom controls too

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hosting, custom-server-controls

I developed a custom control with client capabilities that inherits from `Checkboxlist` class. Does this mean my custom control would have aspnet hosting permissions derived from the parent class or should I declare it again?

This question popped up because the control worked on local host (dev machine) while on IIS and also published into IIS, but didn't on publishing to the hosting server (the client scripts output from the control are not being rendered that's the problem).

For people who don't have faintest idea about aspnet hosting permissions you can spend 5 minute [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspnethostingpermission.aspx)

Comment: Does your hosting party accept the requested permissions?

Comment: I would simply try it and find out

Comment: @Caspar yes it does, i guess it because all other controls that have same capabilities do well when i publish

Comment: @Hasan that's what i am gonna do tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was something different, the time on Server was way back behind like 2011 due to a weak CMOS battery on the board. I set the Date & Time to current, refreshed the page and there it was with all the glory :) have a look at [this post](http://www.geekytidbits.com/webresource-axd-throwing-argumentoutofrangeexception/) for more info